# Terraform only run config that has not changed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created this project where I use terraform to build my cloud architecture. Now the problem is when I make changes or I need something extra in the cloud I just want to add this in my terraform file and when terraform gets executed it does not run the configuration of existing items that did not change. So for example I create an ECR repo, some S3 buckets, a lambda function and some IAM policies but when I make a change I don't want to run everyting that does not need to change because this leeds to errors like `|Error: Resource with name ... already exists`. How I currently execute my terraform is I just run `terraform apply -auto-approve` in my github actions. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi David,
take a look at [lifecycle Meta-argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle), paying particular attention to the ***ignore_changes*** flag!
I think this can help you!

Comment: But with this you cannot say, dont create this resource if it already exist, you can only say ignore changes to this attribute of this resource? Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: for my understanding, terraform does not create resources if they already exist and they are created by Tf itself (resources reside in the Tf state).
Quick question: when you get `|Error: Resource with name ... already exists` is because those resources have been created outside Terraform?

Comment: Hey Nico, btw thanks for looking into my problem. No everything is created by terraform, but currently I'm looking into s3 backend where you store your state in an s3 bucket so it keeps track of what is created. link-> https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3

Comment: just forgot to ask you... if the resource has been created by Terraform, is there any chance it has been modified outside it? Did you change the backend configuration?

Comment: No, but I"ve found a solution, will post answer. But thank you for looking into my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that Terraform keeps a state of your configuration (I'm new to terraform) so for terraform to keep this state in mind you need to configure a backend. This means that you will upload this state file in for example an s3 bucket.
So I will break down the process in a few steps.

#### 1) Create an s3 bucket

In this s3 bucket you will store your *.tfstate file. I had 2 configurations so I created 2 buckets for this. Which each stored their state files.

#### 2) Create IAM policy

You need to create an IAM policy so your account has access to this bucket. you can use the following template.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", "s3:DeleteObject"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/path/to/my/key"
    }
  ]
}
```

I also attached this too my AWS user (not sure if this is necessary)

#### 3) Configure the backend in your terraform

You need to configure your backend in the terraform file. this looks like this.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

You need to run `terraform init` after this to initialize the backend.

Hope this helps other people!

This answer was based of this documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3

Comment: as per [S3 backend configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3).
Please, take a look at the DynamoDB Table Permissions section as well! This can help you locking the state

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a

`terraform apply -target=resource_name.resource_type -auto-approve`

Comment: but with this target option you only run a specific resource, I want to run my whole architecture and only create or update when there are changes. But thanks for looking into this but I've found a solution.

Comment: Oh! Sweet. I'll be looking forward to seeing your solution.

Comment: It is posted above haha.

Comment: Its basically that terraform checks your configuration against the configuration that is stored as the backend (this also gets updated by terraform itself) so then it will only apply changes!